# Provider cable in switch?

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch, vlan, pppoe

Is that possible to get internet connectivity if cable will be plugged into switch port?
Something like that - **Provider - Switch - Router**.

Switch is a L2 managed unit, and router running RouterOS.

I know that this is possible to put DHCP server on VLAN, so maybe this is possible to put DHCP and PPPoE client as well?

So in fact I need something like virtually connect physical interface on my switch to my router.

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say: Um, what?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it will work if you give the 'WAN'-ports on the switch their own VLAN so they're physically separate from the LAN ports.

After all, the switching takes place on layer 2, a lower layer than the routing which takes place on layer 3.

If the switch is dedicated to the WAN traffic you don't even need a VLAN, but that would be a waste of switch-ports in my opinion :-)

Comment: Most useful answer. But i still can't get it to work.

Comment: uh, comments added to by enter.. But i still can't get it to work. I created VLAN interface on mikrotik and put one port to same vlan on switch, as well as added same PVID for that port. But still i'm not able to get PPPoE working. Sorry for that - all that advanced networking is problem for me - still learning :)

Comment: Just to expand Martijn's answer a bit: you need to choose a VLAN, and configure two ports to be untagged for that VLAN (and no other), and PVID set to that VLAN. Then you should find that those ports can send traffic to each other, but not to any other ports.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly where is the modem? Does this router have a [DOCSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS) wan interface? If you want to connect multiple devices to a cable just splice it, that is how cable works (there is no DOCSIS switch device).

Comment: Why docsis? First provider use ordinary copper cable and dhcp server, second (fallback) is adsl, but it works because it plugged directly into router.